# .getField() returning empty result

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

Using the `RethinkdbDash` package for `Node.js` and `Rethink`, I'm able to use this `ReQL`:

```
r.db('<DATABASE>').table('<TABLE>').get('<UUID_FOR_OBJECT>')
```

...to get the desired object out of the database with the following format...

```
{
    "address":  "<ADDRESS>" ,
    "createdAt": Thu Sep 15 2016 02:08:54 GMT+00:00 ,
    "email": <EMAIL>,
    "firstName":  "<FIRST NAME>" ,
    "fullName":  "<FULL NAME>" ,
    "lastName":  "<LAST NAME>" ,
    "middleName":  "<MIDDLE NAME>" ,
    "phone":  "<PHONE NUMBER>" ,
    "prescriptions": [
     {
        "expiresOn": Thu Sep 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
        "hasExpired": false ,
        "name":  "<MEDICATION NAME>" ,
        "prescribedBy":  "<DOCTOR NAME>" ,
        "prescribedOn": Thu Sep 15 2016 02:54:52 GMT+00:00 ,
        "startOn": Thu Sep 15 2016 02:54:52 GMT+00:00 ,
        "uuid":  "f11fed84-30dc-4cf9-af36-b715f303bed1"
      }
    ] ,
    "uuid":  "bd4d6d44-3af3-4224-afef-d7e9a876025b"
}
```

The problem comes when I try to add the `pluck` or `getField` function to the query to isolate and retrieve just the `'prescriptions'` array. This is the function in my controller for the call...

```
export function all(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id

  r.table('Patients').get(id).pluck('prescriptions').run() //Also tried .getField('prescriptions') and .get(id)('prescriptions')
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
      return res.json({ status: 200, data: results })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      return res.json({ status: 400, message: 'There was an error finding the medication of patient ' + id, data: error })
    })
}
```

When I call the API path the access this data and execute the `all` function, I get the following response...

```
{
    status: 200,
    data: []
}
```

The exact same query, however, works as expected within the `Rethink` admin console's data explorer.

Any idea or help as to why this is happening is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Issue was actually with my routes specified with `Express` and nothing to do with `rethinkdb`!